# Deploying Java EE Enterprise Application on AWS

Tags: mysql, angular, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee

New at programming and would really appreciate your help!
Normally i would have a java EE application deployed to glassfish, thereafter i will use the restful apis to query the database (mySQL) using the services in Angular.

Currently i would like to use my application via the internet instead of locally, i am using Angular 9 deployed on firebase and using the firestore as my database. This eliminates the need for local deployment when i need to query the backend database through the restful api. However, this method makes it difficult to create and query data when there are r/s between the objects.

Was hoping to deploy my current java EE application to the AWS so that it is always live - ie. i dont need to locally deploy the application always and with this java ee application, it will link to a AWS RDS database, so thereafter i can just call the restful apis through the angular service to query the database.

I am not sure how to go about doing this method and would appreciate if anyone can guide me through this if the method is possible! Also do suggest any other ways to go about querying a mySQL relational database (that is hosted on the cloud) with angular if the method mentioned is not possible!

Really appreciate it! Thank you!

Edit: Another method of bringing the website live with technologies i am familiar with would be using java ee backed with the enterprise beans together with JSF (managed beans etc) which would require me to deploy my enterprise application (ejb, war) to the cloud if im not mistaken? I have read articles on deploying the war only and was wondering if anyone can guide me in the deployment of the entire enterprise application?

Comment: @Kukeltje tag removed!

Comment: As your question is formulated, you basically state that you have no idea and then describe a pretty complex task. Definitely doable, but as it stands, I personally can't recognize any significant effort on your part. So it's hard to help you in this state.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: But anyway, here are a couple of pointers. Just on the keyword level. I'd package the whole thing (your app + application container, be it glassfish or whatever) in a docker image and push it to private ECR. Then I'd configure an auto-scaling ECS cluster which would run container with this image. Also put a load balancer in front and you're good to go.
And (as we're at it) I'd configure the whole thing in CloudFormation template(s).

Comment: You might also want to check Elastic Beanstalk. It allows you to deploy your JEE app to a prepared environment (I think it supports Glassfish as target platform). It's all the same stuff under the hood (ECS cluster, load balancer etc.), but it's easier to get started.

Comment: @lexicore thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

The first option could be to run an EC2 instance, install glassfish there and run the java ee application same as you have done locally.

Depending on the complexity of the application, the alternative could be using serverless from AWS(lambdas) and making queries to the DB. This approach will require configuring AWS API Gateway also.

Important questions you need to think about: how many requests are you going to serve per some period of time and if you need the service running 24x7. That will help to select appropriate instance type or to decide about lambdas.

Comment: thank you for your response! have looked through the setting up of EC2 but quite worried about the pricing. Have updated my question of another method i think is possible to do and would be grateful if you can help as well!

Comment: @pannd I would not worry about pricing at this stage.

Comment: if the pricing is problematic - you can write lambdas - but that would mean rewriting the application to you. One more option is beanstalk, you can deploy war in that service too, but the pricing won't be lower as in ec2, it wil just simplify scaling if you need it and becides it already has webservers so you can directly upload war there

Comment: @GiorgosDev Upvote for Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @GiorgosDev thank you for your reply!

Comment: I really can't imagine pricing to be so problematic that it would make sense to rewrite the whole thing with lambdas.